# Save image from the web into my Public/images/items folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image, path, webclient

I'm trying to save an image from a website and save it to my `~/Public/images/items` folder.

```
string localFilename = @"~\Public\images\items\" + item.Name + ".png";
string imageUrl = "https://account.hirezstudios.com/smitegame/" + CQ.Create(itemBox)["#itemIcon a img"].Attr("src");
using (var web = new WebClient())
{
    web.DownloadFile(imageUrl, localFilename);
}
```

An exception fired because the path in `localFilename` is not correct.

Here's what the actual variable holds (checked using a breakpoint):

```
~\Public\images\items\Aegis Amulet.png
```

And the exception:

> {"No se puede encontrar una parte de la ruta de acceso 'C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\IIS Express\~\Public\images\items\Aegis
>   Amulet.png'."}

So the path is obviously wrong.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebClient doesn't understand the ~ in a path. You need to have a local full path to where you want to save the file.

Try something like this instead...

```
Server.MapPath(@"\Public\images\items\" + item.Name + ".png")
```

Comment: Can I edit your answer to include the way to get the relative path in ASP.Net MVC4?

Comment: I added Server.MapPath, but if you know of another way, feel free to edit or add your own answer.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was going to add. I'll accept your answer - thank you for your time!